# How to include XML file in node for js map rendering?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have a clickable map that uses js, css and xml to display. I previously was provided solutions in a previous thread  [How do I implement a clickable JavaScript map?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30913/how-do-i-implement-a-clickable-javascript-map) using `drupal_add_css()` and `drupal_add_js()`.

1. Can I add multiple CSS files with `drupal_add_css()` using an array? Or, do I need to list these as separate commands?
2. The other problem is I need to have an XML file to feed the data into the JavaScript file. I attempted to edit the JavaScript file by hardcoding the XML file location, but that doesn't seem to work.

   ```
   $.ajax({type: 'GET',url: 'sites/default/files/repfinder/xml/usaMapSettings.xml'
   ```

What should I be doing so that the JavaScript code recognizes the XML file? Without it, no map is displayed.

Comment: re: 1) you want to add the multiple files one by one with separate commands.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, according to the demo page you showed, the URL is relative to the path where the JavaScript is loaded; adding a slash in front of URL passed to `$.ajax()` should work.

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET', url: '/sites/default/files/repfinder/xml/usaMapSettings.xml'
```